# Is there anyway to fit a breadboard into a 1.5 inch wide space?

Tags: arduino, breadboard, storage, protoboard, space

I am working on a model rocket and want to add electrical parts to it via a breadboard inside.

The space I have to work with is only about 40mm wide.

Is there any kind of breadboard that can fit in this space or any way to modify a breadboard to fit in this space?

Comment: You could get a perfboard instead of a breadboard. (Parts mounted on a breadboard on a model rocket during launch might not stay connected to the breadboard anyway)

Comment: It makes no sense whatsoever to use a breadboard in a model rocket.  Not only are you lofting utterly unecessary mass, you risk unreliability from things moving under the *extreme* acceleration.

Comment: use a perfboard .. it is available with and without copper pads ... https://youtu.be/Ro0_3bzqTkk

Comment: I would not use a solderless breadboard on anything that experiences high acceleration. Use a protoboard.

Comment: This shop sells tiny breadboards:https://detail.tmall.com/item.htm?id=616053907371&spm=a1z1r.7974869.0.0.269c3ad492Pv5C

Comment: Is it a model rocket (i.e. a very small rocket) or a static model of a rocket?

Comment: I wouldn't even use solderless breadboard on something that's going to kick around in a backpack or even the lab for a while, at least once the circuit is (as good as) finalised.  I've got a prototype on the go at the moment, which I'm working on at home and work.  Something comes loose almost every journey.

Comment: @PeteKirkham its an actually rocket, that will fly on rocket motors

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I haven't seen a push-in breadboard that small, but you could verify the circuit on one, and then use a generic solder-able breadboard for the final circuit. These can be found at any major supplier for very low cost. I am not sure how robust it would need to be for your model rocket application, but soldering the components in would likely hold up to vibration better than the push-in style breadboard.

Example:
[Digikey / Sparkfun](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/sparkfun-electronics/PRT-08808/7387401?utm_adgroup=Prototype%20Boards%20Perforated&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Shopping_Product_Prototyping%2C%20Fabrication%20Products_NEW&utm_term=&productid=7387401&gclid=CjwKCAiA4o79BRBvEiwAjteoYP9UjMlp5JzMDHmv9e6x9HKtQK7Nz4Kap699nUWASyKpQGWaHKN_RxoCb_wQAvD_BwE)

Comment: If searching online, use "strip board", It's a generic name for the original "veroboard". Larger ones can be cut to size.

Comment: And if board size is a concern don't go with boards with fancy copper patterns made to minmize the wiring you have to do. Pad-per-hole can be made much more compactly since you choose all the connections and therefore waste no space, but takes extra effort since you lay down every wire.

Comment: Could also use wire wrap instead of soldering.  Even used by NASA so it would be good for your home made model rocket. https://workmanship.nasa.gov/lib/insp/2%20books/links/sections/301_Discrete%20Wiring.html

Comment: Many years ago I actually took part in a launch with electronics assembled on stripboard.  The soldering didn't fail, though the landing was harder than planned (parachute issues) also one instrument failed due a battery discharging a bit and getting cold on an overnight delay.

Answer (score -1):

eBay and AliExpress etc. carry 170 pin breadboards; these measure 35x45mm after you've removed the tabs for snapping it to another board. Trimming 2-3 rows off the end (I used a bench sander) will easily reduce it to 40mm. I'd recommend not using the last row after trimming it, and perhaps filling it with epoxy glue to give it a more solid edge.